# How can I reference a UITextView that resides in a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, swift

What I do now is store a reference to the textView in a variable in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("photoCell") as EditProfileTableViewCell

    cell.imageCaption.tag = indexPath.row
    imageCaptionTextView = cell.imageCaption

    imageCaptionTextView.delegate = self

    return cell

}
```

Then I try to gain access to the textView when I tap the done button on the keyboard that is presented when I click inside it.

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    checkMaxLength(textView, maxLength: 60)

    if text == "\n" {

        imageCaptionTextView.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

I have some other code (not included in this post) that just adds a border around the textView to give the user indication the textView has been clicked in. This only seems to work on the first textView. I also added a tag to the textView and printed to console but the tag returns the same number.

It's quite clear I only seem to have a reference to the first cell. I can't use didSelectRow etc because this cell contains a photo and then a textView for adding the caption for that image.

Is there some simple way to reference my cells? I've looked at examples on stack over flow but they don't include broad enough examples as answers.

Would appreciate some help here.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UITextViewDelegate` has functions for `textViewDidBeginEditing` and `textViewDidEndEditing`.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("photoCell") as EditProfileTableViewCell

    cell.imageCaption.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.imageCaption.delegate = self

    return cell
}

func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView)
{
    textView. // add border here
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView)
{
   textView.text // will give you final value
   textView.tag will give you the row of the cell.
}

func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    checkMaxLength(textView, maxLength: 60)

    if text == "\n" {

        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `UITextView` is added as a subview to your cell's `contentView`, then you can access the enclosing `UITableViewCell` by doing this:

```
UITableViewCell* cell = (id)textField.superview.superview;
```

or:

```
let cell = cell.superview.superview as UITableViewCell?
```

This relies on the assumption that `contentView` is a subview of `UITableViewCell`, which is true up to and including iOS 8, but might cease to be in the future. So, you could add some checks there (e.g., using `isKindOfClass`) in order to be sure that you are getting the right object type.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can do is getting the **selected cell** first.
Then, you can use your tag to access it.

```
NSIndexPath *selectedCellIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedCellIndex];
```

Then, you get your target cell. So, you can use your **tag** to get your **UITextView**.

Here is the link to talk about the UIResponder chain: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html

Comment: This won't work as I have to actually select the cell. Tapping my UITextView doesn't do this,

Comment: Can you try to debug the problem? Check what did get from `selectedCellIndex ` Because UITextView is also inherited from UIResponder. And the touch will be passed. And I believe the UITableView is able to detect that. It's not a new issue I think.